# having problems saving data to a text file

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers

the data isn't saving correctly, the first loop of the for loop gives us random characters, however the following loop gives us the correct numbers

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
int    saveDroneSimResults(delivery_info deliveryinfo, int no_of_deliveries){
        int numdel, i;
        numdel = no_of_deliveries;

        printf("NUM DEL: %d\n\n", numdel);

        FILE file = fopen("results.txt", "w");
        if(file == NULL){

            printf("ERROR! The file failed to open!\n");
            exit(-1);

        }


        for(i=0; i < numdel; i++){

            fprintf(file, "%d %d %19s %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf\n", deliveryinfo[i].deliveryID, 
            deliveryinfo[i].drone_ID, deliveryinfo[i].drone_name, deliveryinfo[i].max_distance , deliveryinfo[i].load_capacity ,
            deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Orig_loc_x , deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Orig_loc_y , deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Desti_loc_x , 
            deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Desti_loc_y , deliveryinfo[i].load_capacity, deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_distance);
        }

        fclose(file);

        return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're not getting an error message, but you're missing * (FILE *file = fopen(...)).

Answer (score 0):

If it is working correctly when i = 1, then you could just change your for loop to:

```
for(i =1; i< numdel; i++)
```

With the code given, I can't know if the rest is wrong as I do not know anything about deliveryinfo. It may help you to debug the code if you separate the one long fprintf into multiple different fprintf statements.

I would change it to:

```
fprintf(file,"%d %d ",deliveryinfo[i].deliveryID, deliveryinfo[i].drone_ID);
fprintf(file, "%19s %.2lf ",deliveryinfo[i].drone_name, deliveryinfo[i].max_distance);
fprintf(file, "%.2lf %.2lf ",deliveryinfo[i].load_capacity ,
            deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Orig_loc_x);
fprintf(file, "%.2lf %.2lf ", deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Orig_loc_y , deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Desti_loc_x );
fprintf(file, "%.2lf %.2lf "deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_Desti_loc_y , deliveryinfo[i].load_capacity);
fprintf(file, "%.2lf\n", deliveryinfo[i].Delivery_distance);
```

Purely to make the code easier for you and anyone else to read in the future. You could have 3 variable per fprintf as well but anything more than 3 becomes more difficult to check quickly.

For further trouble shooting, I recommend you take a look at the contents of delivery info and ensure that what is stored there is correct for what you want.

Edit: as @Majkl pointed out your file open is also wrong. It should be:

```
 FILE *file = fopen("results.txt", "w");
```